# How to Share image + text with facebook in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, sharing

I am writing **facebook interaction** code in swift language for **iOS**. I have converted login and other code but stuck with sharing methods.

I am not able to find `requestWithGraphPath` method of `FBRequest` class in swift. If somebody know about this then please help me here. I have searched for solution on web but fail to find.

This is my sharing code in **Objective-C**

```
 FBRequest *req=[FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error{
        if (!error) {
            // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here                
            NSLog(@"Successful sharing");
        } else {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            NSLog(@"Error while sharing data");
        }
    }];
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there another way to access the methods of class? I have tried like this - FBRequest.requestWithGraphPath

Comment: How to get public permissions by using latest Facebook SDK for post Image with text?