# Swift Facebook share UIImageview image

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uiimageview

I would like to make Facebook share button on my app that shares the image that is loaded from the UIImageview. I cannot figure out how to do it.. There is option to add the text on Facebook share window, but can't add the image. Please help.

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var saveButtonVar: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func facebookBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        var facebookBtn : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            facebookBtn.setInitialText("I am sharing my motivation with you!")
            facebookBtn.addImage(UIImage(named: "motImg")) //????
        self.presentViewController(facebookBtn, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func twitterBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    }





    @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.image, nil, nil, nil)

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved!", message:
            "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }




    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

        load_image("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26347781/Images/Image\(arc4random_uniform(17) + 1).jpg")

        saveButtonVar.hidden = false


    }

    func load_image(urlString:String)
    {

        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.image.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
        })

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        saveButtonVar.hidden = true

        image.image = UIImage(named: "motImg")



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

Integrate FacebookShare sdk.

People can share photos from your app to Facebook with the Share Dialog or with a custom interface:

-Photos must be less than 12MB in size.

-People need the native Facebook for iOS app installed, version 7.0 or higher

```
@IBAction func facebookBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
  let shareImage = SharePhoto()
  shareImage.image = imageView.image //Image from your imageview
  shareImage.isUserGenerated = true

  let content = SharePhotoContent()
  content.photos = [shareImage]

  let sharedDialoge = ShareDialog()
  sharedDialoge.shareContent = content

  sharedDialoge.fromViewController = self
  sharedDialoge.mode = .automatic


  if(sharedDialoge.canShow)
  {
    sharedDialoge.show()
  }
  else
  {
    print("Install Facebook client app to share image")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hei there!

Check out this guy's answer:
[Swift UIActivityViewController Image&Url Share not working with FB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842248/swift-uiactivityviewcontroller-imageurl-share-not-working-with-fb)

For many people it seemed to work the example in the link, so maybe it does for you, too.
However, so far it did not work for me and I came across your question while still investigating my problem.

As far as adding text, I know this functionality is off for some time, but you should be able to add an url link.

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?