# Swift UIActivityViewController Image&Url Share not working with FB

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController to share image. After the Facebook recent changes . I am able share an image and Url individualy but i am unable to share both image and url at a time. The same code works fine with Mail, twitter etc., Not sure what i am missing for Facebook.

```
func shareImage() {
    var myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    var img: UIImage = currentPhoto!
    var shareItems:Array = [img, myWebsite]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have modified your code for swift 2.0:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    let img: UIImage = image!

    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }

    let shareItems:Array = [img, url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And it is posting a picture with URL.

Result with this code:

[image]

Comment: your Facebook native App version?

Comment: I have too and it is working fine.. Try to post with another device.

Comment: Sorry buddy I have no idea why it is not working. Wait for another answer if any body knows about this issue.

Comment: No you can not because predefined text will be ignored.

Comment: As I said you can not add text.. :)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni If facebook app is installed in my device then it is allow to share only image but if app is not install in device then it will allow to share text,link and image.Can you say me why it is not allowed when facebook app is installed in device?

Comment: @Bhumika I am not getting your issue.

Comment: I am able to share image and text both when facebook app is not installed in my device.so can you say me reason why it is not allowed to me when app is installed in device?

Comment: @Bhumika can you share any demo project?

Comment: No.But currently i have implemented using facebook graph API.and it is working fine.Thanks

Comment: @DharmeshKheni how can i achieve this in objective c ?

Comment: Not working for me neither. For those who have this working, what is the version of Facebook/iOS on the device ?

Comment: I tried to post the image on Facebook but not posting. Only can able to share URL.. Can't we share an image/video on Facebook using UIActivityViewController?

Comment: Does not work for me. Sharing image and text with included url. Image does not get shared.

Answer (score 6):

SWIFT 3

```
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string: visitedlink)

    let img: UIImage = UIImage(named:"Logo")!

    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }

    let shareItems:Array = [img,url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo]
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried to post the image on Facebook but not posting. Only can able to share URL.. Can't we share an image/video on Facebook using UIActivityViewController?

Comment: Will recently you can't you have to use there own SDK :( @AnandGautam

Comment: Correct @Safad Funy , but we can share an image on Facebook using SLComposeViewController, but need to use FB SDK for Video share.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Implement the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. Support text, URL and image.

```
func doShare() {
    let viewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["ScreenSort for iOS.", URL.init(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1170886809")!], applicationActivities: nil)
    viewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

extension YourViewController: UIActivityItemSource {
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return ""
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        return URL.init(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1170886809")!
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return "ScreenSort for iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1170886809"
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To share image and text**

```
        let imgShare : UIImage = UIImage(named: "store")!
        let textToShare = "Image form My app."

        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, imgShare]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```