# Share Image Via URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, share

I am creating Images app from my WordPress website with json and i am using swift, i want to share image on Social Networks from my app , currently i tried this code it works but only with image name i want to share image from image url, is that possible ?

this is my code

```
 let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "nice")

           let img: UIImage = UIImage(named:"splash")!

           guard let url = myWebsite else {
               print("nothing found")
               return
           }

           let shareItems:Array = [img,url]
           let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.print, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo]
        self!.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift UIActivityViewController Image&Url Share not working with FB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842248/swift-uiactivityviewcontroller-imageurl-share-not-working-with-fb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to download an image and then share you should do that separately, there is no single method that does that for you. Here is how:

```swift
func shareImageFromUrl(_ string: String) {

    guard let myUrl = URL(string: string) else {
        print("Invalid url!")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: data) else
        { return }

        let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.print, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo]
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'"

Comment: Forgot to add `DispatchQueue`. Check once again. Hope it works fine now.